# strange behavior when concatenating strings in VBA

Tags: vba, string, outlook, save, string-concatenation

Here's what I'm trying to do.

We occasionally get emails that has the following info:

Name: In the subject line between ( and -

DoB: In the e-mail Body:

date for receving e-mail: In the mail item itself.

I can get the name and date easily enough, but the DoB is behaving strange when I try to add it to the file name, it'll usually discard the name I've extracted.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub SaveAsPDF(MyMail As MailItem)
' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime ###
' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Word Object Library ###
' --- In VBE click TOOLS > REFERENCES and check the boxes for both of the above ---
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strSaveName As String
Dim blnOverwrite As Boolean
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim sendEmailAddr As String
Dim clientName As String
Dim openPos1 As Integer
Dim closePos1 As Integer
Dim openPos2 As Integer
Dim closePos2 As Integer
Dim senderName As String
Dim looper As Integer
Dim plooper As Integer
Dim strID As String
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim bDay As String


strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
emailSubject = CleanFileName(oMail.Subject)

' ### Get username portion of sender email address  ###
sendEmailAddr = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
senderName = Left(sendEmailAddr, InStr(sendEmailAddr, "@") - 1)

' ### Get Client birthday ###
openPos1 = InStr(oMail.Body, "DOB:")
closePos1 = InStr(oMail.Body, "TLF:")
bDay = Mid(oMail.Body, openPos1 + 12, closePos1 - openPos1 - 12)



' ### USER OPTIONS ###
blnOverwrite = False ' False = don't overwrite, True = do overwrite

' ### Path to save directory ###
bPath = "C:\Email test\"

' ### Create Directory if it doesnt exist ###
If Dir(bPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MkDir bPath
End If

' ### Get Email subject & set name to be saved as ###
saveName = clientName & " " & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".mht"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' ### Get the client name from the email subject ###
openPos2 = InStr(emailSubject, "(")
closePos2 = InStr(emailSubject, "-")
clientName = Mid(emailSubject, openPos2 + 1, closePos2 - openPos2 - 1)
' ### Increment filename if it already exists ###
If blnOverwrite = False Then
    looper = 0
    Do While fso.FileExists(bPath & saveName)
        looper = looper + 1
        saveName = clientName & " " & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & looper & ".mht"
        Loop
Else
End If

' ### Save .mht file to create pdf from Word ###
oMail.SaveAs bPath & saveName, olMHTML
    pdfSave = bPath & clientName & " " & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".pdf"
If fso.FileExists(pdfSave) Then
    plooper = 0
    Do While fso.FileExists(pdfSave)
    plooper = plooper + 1
    pdfSave = bPath & clientName & " " & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & plooper & ".pdf"
    Loop
Else
End If


' ### Open Word to convert .mht file to PDF ###
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

' ### Open .mht file we just saved and export as PDF ###
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=bPath & saveName, Visible:=True)
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
            pdfSave, ExportFormat:= _
            wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
            wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

wrdDoc.Close
wrdApp.Quit

' ### Delete .mht file ###
Kill bPath & saveName


Set oMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

This will save a PDF file with the name like "Marty Smith 04-06-2020" however if I add the String "bDay" into the file name, it'll disregard the name, and the DOB, and only add the date, but Word will fail to save and hang in a background process.

```
' ### Save .mht file to create pdf from Word ###
oMail.SaveAs bPath & saveName, olMHTML
    pdfSave = bPath & clientName & " " & bDay & " " & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".pdf"
If fso.FileExists(pdfSave) Then
    plooper = 0
    Do While fso.FileExists(pdfSave)
    plooper = plooper + 1
    pdfSave = bPath & clientName & " " & bDay & " " & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & plooper & ".pdf"
    Loop
Else
End If
```

Comment: It's possible there is at least one character in `bDay` which is not valid in a filename.  Try using `Debug.Print` to output the filename and check it's what you expect.

Comment: You are assigning a part of the mail body to `bDay` - probably you have invalid chars in it, eg a Newline character. Put a statement like `Debug.Print "[" & bDay & "]"` after you set the variable and check what's in there.

Comment: Yep. Looks like I got 2 NewLines in there. Not sure how, however, as I thought I only got the DOB, and fiddling with the positions don't seem to get rid of it.

Any way I can clean the output?

Comment: As the birthday probably doesn't have a newline within, you are likely off with the positions. But if you cannot figure that out: You could use a simple statement like `bDay = Replace(Replace(bDay, vbCr, ""), vbLf, "")`.

Comment: I found where I was going wrong, I was decreasing the wrong position. Adding 14 to ClosePos did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My closing position for InStr included 2 newlines from the Email body, that wasn't apparent to me when I was showing the output via Msgbox.

Debug.Print bDay helped me to see what the issue was and adjusting the closePos variable to remove the newlines.